# Cómo acceder a etiquetas anidadas de JSON en python: 13 niveles

Tags: python-3.x, json

Estoy tratando de recorrer un JSON Y obtener los valores de los tags para insertar en la BBDD
Tengo el siguiente código para obtener el json:

```
url_ = '...'
with urllib.request.urlopen(url_) as url:
    data_json = json.loads(url.read().decode())
```

y este es el resultado:

```
[
  {
    "id": xxxx,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": xxxx,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": xxxx,
            "children": [
              {
                "id": xxxx,
                "children": [
                  {
                    "id": xxxx,
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "id": xxxx,
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "id": xxxx,
                            "children": [
                              {
                                "id": xxxx,
                                "children": [
                                  {
                                    "id": xxxx,
                                    "children": [
                                      {
                                        "id": xxxx,
                                        "children": [
                                            {
                                            "id": xxxx,
                                            "children": [
                                              {
                                                "id": xxxx,
                                                "children": []
```

y necesito acceder a todos los [children] anidados para insertar los ids en la bbdd.

Mi código funciona pero es horrible:

```
ids = []
for nd1 in data_json:
    ids.append(nd1['id'])
    hChild = "children" in nd1
    if hChild:
        for nd2 in nd1['children']:
            ids.append(nd2['id'])
            hChild = "children" in nd2
            if hChild:
                for nd3 in nd2['children']:
                    ids.append(nd3['id'])
                    hChild = "children" in nd3
                    if hChild:
                        for nd4 in nd3['children']:
                            ids.append(nd4['id'])
                            hChild = "children" in nd4
                            if hChild:
                                for nd5 in nd4['children']:
                                    ids.append(nd5['ccm2_Id'])
                                    hChild = "children" in nd5
                                    if hChild:
                                        for nd6 in nd5['children']:
                                            ids.append(nd6['ccm2_Id'])
                                            if hChild:
                                                for nd7 in nd6['children']:
                                                    ids.append(nd7['id'])
                                                    hChild = "children" in nd7
                                                    if hChild:
....
```

He tratado de acceder a los nodos de la siguiente manera:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(it.chain.from_iterable(
i['children'][0]['children'][0]['children'] for i in data_json))
```

pero esto no es recursivo, me permite acceder al tercer nivel solamente.

¿Hay alguna forma de obtener el número de nodos de un JSON y recorrerlos de una forma más amigable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas saber el *número de nodos* o de niveles para procesar los datos, ya que puedes ir accediendo a los nodos de manera recursiva, gracias a que la estructura se repite en cada nivel del *json*.

Podemos definir una rutina para procesar cada *nivel*, que se encargue de determinar si existe un nivel inferior y llamarse a si misma con los elementos de dicho nivel.

Por ejemplo, el código a continuación es equivalente al de tu pregunta, ya que extrae todos los `ids` presentes en el *json*:

```
def procesarNodo(ids, nodo):
    if "id" in nodo:
        ids.append(nodo['id'])
    elif "ccm2_Id" in nodo:
        ids.append(nodo['ccm2_Id'])
    if "children" in nodo:
        for nodohijo in nodo['children']:
            procesarNodo(ids, nodohijo)

ids = []
for nd1 in data_json:
    procesarNodo(ids, nd1)

print(ids)
```

Tus datos de ejemplo solamente muestran un atributo `id`, pero tu código hace referencia al atributo `ccm2_Id` en ciertos niveles, por lo que he añadido soporte para agregar uno u otro, asumiendo que los nodos que tienen `ccm2_id` no tienen `id`, ajustalo de acuerdo a la estructura real de tus datos.

Comment: Buenísimo!! Gracias por tu aportación, me facilita mucho la vida.

Answer (score 1):

Esta función recursiva te permite recorrer los distintos niveles de anidamiento conservando el id del nivel superior en caso de que quieras incluirlo como información en la BD.

```
import json

# Datos de prueba con algunos niveles de anidamiento suficientes para generalizar
dataFromUrl = '[{"id": 10, "children": [{ "id": 3, "children":[{ "id": 27, "children":[{ "id": 2, "children":[]}]}]}]}]'
data_json = json.loads(dataFromUrl)
# print(data_json)

def recorrerRecursivo(nodo, padre):
    # Asume que nodo es un array de un elemento y que están
    # presentes las claves id y children
    if len(nodo) == 0: # Terminar la recursión ?
        print('Nodo vacío')
        return
    # Aqui está disponible el id actual y el id "padre"
    # Se puede realizar inserciones en la BD u otras acciones
    print (nodo[0]['id'], ' : ', padre)
    recorrerRecursivo(nodo[0]['children'], nodo[0]['id']) # siguiente nivel inferior
    return

# 0 es el id padre inicial
recorrerRecursivo(data_json, 0)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportación! Muy útil tambien.